# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an instance of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So I'm trying to make a create page but when I try and submit the values on the create page I get a weird error message. I have made a dozen pages like this one and it never happened before.

Here's my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        RiskActionplanViewModel vm = new RiskActionplanViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int? riskId, int? actionplanId, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Domain.Models.RiskActionplan riskActionplan = new Domain.Models.RiskActionplan()
            {
                riskId = riskId,
                actionplanId = actionplanId
            };

            _manager.InsertRiskActionplan(riskActionplan);
            return RedirectToAction("Search", "MainRiskanalysis");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My manager code:

```
    public Models.RiskActionplan InsertRiskActionplan(Models.RiskActionplan riskActionplan)
    {
        using (var context = new Entities.DanoneRiskanalysisContext())
        {
            // Validations
            if (riskActionplan == null) throw new Exception("Riskanalysis is null");
            if (riskActionplan.id > 0) throw new Exception("ID's are given by the database");

            Entities.RiskActionplan entityRiskActionplan = new Entities.RiskActionplan()
            {
                RiskId = riskActionplan.riskId,
                ActionplanId = riskActionplan.actionplanId
            };

            context.Add(entityRiskActionplan);
            context.SaveChanges();

            riskActionplan.id = entityRiskActionplan.Id;
        }
        return riskActionplan;
    }
```

Exception message from Stackify Prefix:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an instance of type 'RiskActionplan' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetOrCreateEntry
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add
>   at DanoneRiskanalysis.Domain.DanoneRiskanalysisManager.InsertRiskActionplan
>   at DanoneRiskanalysis.Web.Controllers.RiskActionplanController.Create

After I submit my form I get redirected to this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.EnsureActionResultNotNull(ObjectMethodExecutor executor, IActionResult actionResult)

Does anyone have a clue of what could be wrong here?

Comment: Your type apparently doesn't have a primary key and entity framework doesn't like that. Whatever InsertRiskActionplan is, it's not using a valid entity type per entity framework rules

Comment: Well, **read the error message!** - it clearly says: *Unable to track .... `RiskActionplan` because it does not have a primary key* - so add a PK and you're done!!

Comment: Also, paste error messages as text and not as images. Images are hard to read, they cannot be searched, and often times are blocked (someone working in an office). Not to mention its a whole lot easier to copy/paste text then it it's to screen shot and upload an image and then link to it

Comment: @marc_s I did read it but where should i add a PK to? I never ever had to do this when creating similar features.

Comment: To my seeing InsertRickActionplan should be fine, i added the code above. & alright, will try not to do that in the future. Thanks for letting me know! @pinkfloydx33

Comment: How about editing in the error messages *now*?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation in past. If corresponding table does not a have primary key adding [Key] attribute to the (logical primary key) property/properties of the entity solved the problem.

Comment: So yeah, adding the [Key] did not help me out. What my problem was was that i added the primary key in my database after i scaffolded and that was what caused the problem. By re-scaffolding i solved my problem.